# Ignoring properties in Jackson if either getter or setter is missing (or is not visible)

Tags: java, jackson

I would like ONLY serialization/deserialization of properties that have BOTH getter/setter methods and the methods are PUBLIC. If either the getter or setter method is missing (or is not PUBLIC) then property should be ignore.

In below example properties 'foo' and 'bar' should both be ignored because of missing getter and non-public setter methods, respectively:

```
class FooBar
{
 public FooBar(int foo, int bar)
 {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
 }

 public int getFoo()
 {
 }

 public void setBar(int b)
 {
  this.bar = bar;
 }

 protected int getBar()
 {
return bar;
}

 private int foo;
 private int bar;
}
```

Possible to do this using Jackson? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has two mechanisms for filtering unwanted properties. Most commonly used is filtering by annotations (@JsonIgnore, @JsonIgnoreProperties). There are many samples in explaining the usage (e.g. https://springframework.guru/jackson-annotations-json/).

But if you really wish to use a custom filtering of properties based on custom conditions, then you can use filtering (see this post as reference https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-filter-annotation.html). This way you can build your own rules of serialization.

Here's a sample code that illustrates this technique:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class M4 {

    private static final String MY_FILTER_NAME = "myFilter";

    @JsonFilter(MY_FILTER_NAME)
    public static class MyPojo {

        private int a;
        private int b;
        private int c;

        public MyPojo(int a, int b, int c) {

            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        public int getA() {

            return a;
        }

        public void setA(int a) {

            this.a = a;
        }

        public void setB(int b) {

            this.b = b;
        }

        public int getC() {

            return c;
        }

        private void setC(int c) {

            this.c = c;
        }
    }


    private static class MySimpleBeanPropertyFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {

        @Override protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {

            return super.include(writer);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {

            String setter = "set" + StringUtils.capitalize(writer.getName());
            String getter = "get" + StringUtils.capitalize(writer.getName());
            Class<?> declaringClass = writer.getMember().getDeclaringClass();
            Method[] methods = declaringClass.getMethods();
            return hasPublicMethod(setter, methods) && hasPublicMethod(getter, methods);
        }

        private boolean hasPublicMethod(String methodName, Method[] methods) {

            return Stream.of(methods)
                .filter(m -> Objects.equals(m.getName(), methodName))
                .anyMatch(m -> Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers()));
        }
    }


    private static class MyFilterProvider extends FilterProvider {

        @Override public BeanPropertyFilter findFilter(Object filterId) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override public PropertyFilter findPropertyFilter(Object filterId, Object valueToFilter) {

            if (Objects.equals(filterId, MY_FILTER_NAME)) {

                return new MySimpleBeanPropertyFilter();
            }
            return super.findPropertyFilter(filterId, valueToFilter);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writer().with(new MyFilterProvider()).writeValue(System.out, new MyPojo(0, 1, 3));
    }

}
```